# How to get the value of a key on the descendant node of ‘object’

Tags: javascript

Why can't I always get the value of d?
I want to get the value of the specified node in a deeper object, which may be a string, a number, or a complex object.

```js
var a = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: {
      f: 3
    },
    d: 2
  }
}

function fun(foo, key) {
  for (var f in foo) {
    if (f == key) {
      return foo[f];
    } else {
      fun(foo[f], key)
    }
  }
}
console.log(fun(a, 'd'));
```

Comment: It seems your algorithm is incorrect. Plus, you don't always return a result, so that's why you get `undefined` very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the key exists in the object you are examining, return it directly.
Else, browse each property to see if it contains it. As soon as you find a value, return it.

Be careful: if you have two nested properties with the same key, it will only get you the first. Auto-discovery is not magical.

```js
var a = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: {
      f: 3
    },
    d: 2
  }
}

function fun(obj, key) {
  if(obj[key]) return obj[key];
  for (var prop in obj) {
      var result = fun(obj[prop], key);
      if(result) return result;
  }
}
console.log(fun(a, 'd'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine.

Comment: @yakiler Glad it helps you! Please mark the answer as accepted so that it can keep helping people finding this post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your algorithm. It returns the correct value when the key matches but the function stack is not propagating that value to the `console.log` function.

Try updating the function in such a way that it propagates the value properly. An example is as follow:

```js
var a = { a: 1, b: { c: { f: 3 }, d: 2 } }
function fun(foo, key) {
  let x = undefined;
  for (var f in foo) {
    if (f == key) {
      x = foo[f];
    } else {
      x = fun(foo[f], key)
    }
  }
  return x;
}
console.log(fun(a, 'd'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this modification of debugging is normal to complete each branch condition, it seems that I am still not familiar with the idea of recursion